# 1C Comconnector - Номер документа

Tags: c#, 1с

Подключаюсь из C# через comconnector к 1С базе и создаю новый ПриходныйКассовыйОрдер и вроде бы все отлично, но вот номер документа присваеваемый из моего кода начал исчисляться от 1, хотя с теми же параметрами (номера счетов, статья, организация и пр.) уже существуют записи в БД.
При создании вручную непосредственно из 1С, номер выдается как положено (1800+).

```
        var Bank = result.Документы.ПриходныйКассовыйОрдер.СоздатьДокумент();

        Bank.УстановитьНовыйНомер();

        *... Буквыцифры ...*

        Bank.Проведен = true;
        Bank.ОбменДанными.Загрузка = true;

        Bank.Записать();
```

Вопрос: как делать корректный инкремент номера ПКО?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить установку нового номера после заполнения реквизитов документа.
Обработчики установки номера документа могут использовать эти данные для генерации префикса документа. Примерно так:

```
    var Bank = result.Документы.ПриходныйКассовыйОрдер.СоздатьДокумент();

    *... Буквыцифры ...*

    Bank.УстановитьНовыйНомер();
    Bank.Проведен = true;
    Bank.ОбменДанными.Загрузка = true;

    Bank.Записать();
```

Comment: Это решает проблему, благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Если ещё актуально, то можно взять максимальный номер документа и прибавить ему "1"

Answer (score 0):

Нужно посмотреть код конфигурации. Возможно там вызывается Bank.УстановитьНовыйНомер("Префикс"). Будет совершенно другой номер.